# How to change the values on x axis using ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting

I want to change the numbers on my x axis, such that instead of {1,2,3,...,19}  it goes like {-9,-8,-7,...,-1,0,1,2,...,8,9}; I used "Tick" command to do that but it's not giving me what I think it should. I would like to know how to fix it.

```
 data = {0.1498203266920634`, 1.1211218617133194`, 
 0.13934946727172953`, 0.08452298683433374`, 0.05761559918451332`, 
 0.045347990294276386`, 0.03776724542918593`, 0.03297918955677359`, 
 0.029679237366153504`, 0.027439862922471827`, 0.02590944157123406`,
 0.025005619290704686`, 0.02460931658677084`, 0.02486291217457186`,
 0.025733066368014243`, 0.028244089602210722`, 
 0.031564725843094193`, 0.056876141227115574`, 
 0.034343974936015445`};

 ene = ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All, 
 Ticks -> {{-9, 1, 9}, Automatic}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option [`DataRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html):

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All, 
  DataRange -> {-9, 9},    
  Ticks -> {Range[-9, 9], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All, 
  DataRange -> {-9, 9},    
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Range[-9, 9], Automatic}}]
```

[image]